# Grails 3.0 logging and monitoring tool for sql and performace

Tags: java, postgresql, grails, java-melody

I'm searching for logging sql tools for grails 3.0. I tried to install java melody, but it couldn't resolve dependencies, so i guess it's for grails 2.*. (Let me know if this is not correct).
I'm looking for a tool where i can see all the queries and their time execution, and not just log the queries in the console.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To see grails3 plugins visit: https://bintray.com/grails/plugins.

Also take a look at this one: https://bintray.com/grails/plugins/p6spy-ui/view

Comment: I get Error Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testRuntime', for this plugin as well. I use grails 3.0.10. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Grails 3 is based on Spring Boot, so following https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuideAdvanced#spring-boot-app should work for you.

By the way, new portal with Grails 3 plugins is http://grails-plugins.org/